# How to group by date regardless of time?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to group by Date(). I've got 3 records with the `created_at` column:

```
2011-12-03 08:00:24, 2011-12-03 08:12:10, 2011-12-04 09:00:00
```

I'd like to only group by year, month and day, regardless of time. So for the example above. It should only return two rows:

```
2011-12-03 and 2011-12-04
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should allow you to group by year month and day

```
 SELECT group_by_column
      , DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y')
      , DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m')
      , DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d')
   FROM my_table
  GROUP BY group_by_column
```

or if you want to do them all together.

```
 SELECT group_by_column
      , DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y%m%d')
   FROM my_table
  GROUP BY group_by_column
```

Comment: In Rails 3, AR: `Foobar.group('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y%m%d")')`. Thanks for that

Answer (score 8):

```
... group by date(date_time_column)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the following?

```
SELECT 
    DATE(created_at) AS created_date 
FROM 
    my_table 
GROUP BY 
    created_date
```

Comment: Yes, this groups it by date and time

Answer (score 2):

MySQL permits `GROUP BY DATE(created_at)`. So that would translate in ActiveRecord to `.group(DATE(created_at))`

In fact, that exact example is available in the [Rails Guides on ActiveRecord querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Date() function.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

```
mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
        -> '2003-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
   GROUP BY DATE(`date_column`)
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)