# SQL to get count by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the number of rows in a table for each date. Right now I am doing:

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(*)) FROM videos_videoview GROUP BY date
```

What would be the correct syntax for the above?

In addition, the date is stored not as a date, but as datetime (2012-01-25 10:26:20). How would I `GROUP BY` date here, ignoring the time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to group by date regardless of time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375800/how-to-group-by-date-regardless-of-time)

Comment: So many duplicates, which one to pick....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), the `DATE()` function truncates a timestamp down to a date.

```
select DATE(date),count(1)
from videos_videoview
group by DATE(date);
```

Honestly, this is very, very basic SQL.  Please read through the documentation of whatever RDBMS you're using or get a basic book on SQL.

Documentation: read it. Love it. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

select date, count(*) from videos_videoview group by date;

Which DB are you using?